# Redux Toolkit Thunk difference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I was searching about thunks on Redux-toolkit and I found 2 ways of dealing with them:

**createAsyncThunk** or just using **async + dispatch**

Using createAsyncThunk:

```
export const deleteColumnAndTasks = createAsyncThunk(
  'yourSlice/deleteColumnAndTasks',
  async ({ boardId, column }) => {
    const tasksToDelete = column.taskIds || [];
    await changeBoardColumns({
      operationType: 'delete',
      targetBoardId: boardId,
      columnId: column.id
    });
    await deleteColumn({ columnId: column.id });
    await Promise.all(tasksToDelete.map(taskId => deleteTask({ taskId })));
  }
);
```

Using async + dispatch

```
export const deleteColumnAndTasks = ({ boardId, column }) => async dispatch => {
  const tasksToDelete = column.taskIds || [];
  try {
    await dispatch(changeBoardColumns({
      operationType: 'delete',
      targetBoardId: boardId,
      columnId: column.id
    }));
    await dispatch(deleteColumn({ columnId: column.id }));
    await Promise.all(tasksToDelete.map(taskId => dispatch(deleteTask({ taskId }))));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error deleting column and tasks', error);
  }
};
```

What is the difference between the two ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both are designed to dispatch actions to change the state of the store. They both will return a Promise object as written. That is where the similarities end.

`createAsyncThunk()` is a factory that registers and returns a function ([action creator](https://redux.js.org/usage/reducing-boilerplate#action-creators)) that *will be called in the future* and that is designed to return a Promise object. [The docs state](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk):

> It generates promise lifecycle action types based on the action type
> prefix that you pass in, and returns a thunk action creator that will
> run the promise callback and dispatch the lifecycle actions based on
> the returned promise.

Also [Life Cycle Actions](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#promise-lifecycle-actions) from the docs

> `createAsyncThunk` will generate three Redux action creators using
> `createAction`: `pending`, `fulfilled`, and `rejected`. Each lifecycle action
> creator will be attached to the returned thunk action creator so that
> your reducer logic can reference the action types and respond to the
> actions when dispatched. Each action object will contain the current
> unique requestId and arg values under `action.meta`.

So if it is an important design choice to keep track/monitor/subscribe to the async actions you are dispatching, `createAsyncThunk()` provides you the means to do all of that with no extra effort on your own.

For example, in a `createSlice()` call one can do something like this:

```js
extraReducers: builder =>
  builder
    .addCase(deleteColumnAndTasks.pending, (state, action) => {
      // do pending action
    })
    .addCase(deleteColumnAndTasks.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.value = [action.payload, ...state.value];
    })
    // etc.
)
```

One other important capability that `createAsyncThunk()` provides is the ability to easily [cancel the async action](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#cancellation) based upon a user defined `condition`.

=====

The second example is simply a synchronously executed (at call time) function that uses [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36321/9078341) to pass in `boardId`, `column` and a reference the to `dispatch` function. All of the tooling provided automagically by `createAsyncThunk()` does not exist. Those features, if required will need to be written separately.

Comment: wow, thanks! It makes a lot of sense :)